# Array has an object but has no length or data

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I simply cannot understand whats going on with this code, it's from my Angular project, basically I have a list of objectives but it's acting very weird in the subscription.

This is the ngOnInit method:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.objectivesService.getObjectives();
        this.objectivesSub = this.objectivesService._loadedObjectives.subscribe(objectives => {
            this.objectives = objectives;
            console.log(this.objectives)
            console.log(`First Object: ${this.objectives[0]}`)
            console.log(`Length: ${this.objectives.length}`)
        })
    }
```

and these are the logs
[image: Logs]

can someone explain whats going on and how to fix it? It seems to know it has data (first log) but then it just forgets it?

EDIT: Managed to fix it, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is there any other code that will update the `this.objectives`' value? For example: `this.objectivesService.getObjectives();`?

Comment: That gets the objectives from firebase and updates a BehaviorSubejct named *_loadedObejctives* in the service, which I am subscribing to in the ngOnInit, so in the subscription I should get the current objectives from firebase, and I do as you see in the first log, but the other two seem to forget that, other than the getObjectives method there aren't any other operations being done that could do that, in fact inside the application an IonLabel shows the length of the array is one and the values show as intended, but the ts code seems to disagree

Comment: Is the array's first index still undefined if you move the second log before the first?

Comment: @JosephWebber yes, and if i try to print the full array later it prints it fine, but the first index is always undefined when logged, and the length attribute is always 0, even though the full array shows the data correctly as shown in the picture

Comment: Would be great if you can reproduce the error in StackBlitz.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try by pushing the items in the array 'objectives'.
I tried to replicate this by writing plain javascript as below :

```
    name: 'test',
   description: 'testDescription',
   id:'testId',
   notes:'notes'
  };
  objectives:any[]=[];
  ngOnInit(){
    this.objectives.push(this.data);
    console.log(this.objectives)
            console.log(`First Object: ${this.objectives[0]}`)
            console.log(`Length: ${this.objectives.length}`)

  }
```

this seems to be working as expected. You can refer the whole code by following this sample [application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cmra1g?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter).

Let me know if this is what you are looking for( mark it is as your answer if it is ) , otherwise please share the code for us to review throughly.

Comment: I tried to do that but i cannot loop through the array that i get back from the subscription because it also says it's length is 0, the forEach method doesn't work even though if i tell it to print the array it prints it perfectly with the data and says it's length is 1. That's why it's so confusing, it says it has data but none of the proprieties or methods work in the code, i'll try to provide more code

Comment: This is the code for the Objectives Service and the Objectives Page [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/9Zsb9L1j)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something was wrong in the Objectives Service and the getObjectives() was not updating the BehaviorSubject correctly, changed the order of the .next(objectives) command and it now waits for all the data from the DB before sending the array. I don´t know why it worked to print the array but not the length or the first item but it is fixed now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).